# SSRS Line Chart: Adding an Average/Target line to Line Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but it has so far eluded me.

## My current report:

- I have a dataset of employees' absences at my company.
- It is essentially broken down by department, date and time lost.
- I have charted this as below:

[image: current]

- The manager is shown their own departments dynamically using a **filter** on the **series group**.
- By using a report level filter I can cache the dataset overnight for all departments.

## My preferred report:

- In order to give some context to the data I would really like to add another line showing the same data for the whole organisation.
- This data is already captured and I can add that "department" for all users so they get a graph as below (new line in blue with square markers):
  [image: preferred]
- The trouble is that I want the extra line to appear completely differently to the existing lines

  1. **I don't want the extra line to have markers necessarily**
  2. **I don't want the extra line to appear in the same legend**
  3. **I don't want the extra line to have an action (i.e. be clickable)**

In my perfect world, there wouldn't even be a line, just a change in background colour above and below where the line would be. I haven't been able to find a pretty example of what I am talking about so instead I have produced this hideous travesty in ms paint:

[image: travesty]

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can change all of that information/treatment by modifying the series.

Firstly change the **Chart Type** of the series to Area
[image]

Which gives you something like....

[image]

All other settings you mention can be done in the series properties

eg

1. Right Click Series, Select Properties, Legend, Check the box marked
   [Do not show this series in the legend]
2. Set the Action (in series properties) to None
3. Set the markers as you want

Comment: Thank you, this looks ideal. The issue I am now having is to indepently filter the two series. I want each showing data from the same column, from the same dataset, but for different departments.

Comment: Have you tried adding a series group to your chart?

Comment: I'm using the series group to specify the grouping for the X axis (in this case month). This works but I'm beginning to think it might be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved partial success using the ***StripLines*** property for the ***Y Axis***:

[image: partial]

Screenshot of setting:

[image: settings]

- I added a ***Member*** then changed the ***BackgroundColor*** and ***StripWidth***.
- The ***StripWidth*** determines the height of the shaded area and can be an expression.